# How to get id of last row inserted in oracle

Tags: oracle

I'm working with an oracle table that has an insert trigger that fetches the next value from a sequence and uses that as the primary key id.

I cannot change the database, so I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve the assigned id from a newly inserted row.

select max(id) would work if there was only one user, but that is not the case.

Is there a way to do this?

Versions:

```
NLSRTL                                  11.2.0.3.0  Production
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition  11.2.0.3.0  64bit Production
PL/SQL                                  11.2.0.3.0  Production
TNS for Linux:                          11.2.0.3.0  Production
```

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/334501?tstart=0

Comment: do you want the current value of the sequence? if yes and you are using PL/SQL Developer than you can check it in the Object browser under the  Sequences. If you are not, then see that thread: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4245421000346226872

Comment: Does the table have a date/timestamp column that is set on insert that you could use to determine the last row?

Comment: Also, are you trying to do this in the trigger or is this something that you want to do at a later date independent of the trigger?

Comment: Aside from the techincal soluitons offered, this sounds like a good place to ask what is the business problem you are trying to solve?  When do you need to get this value, and what will you do with it?  Sometimes the best answer is to re-define the problem.

Comment: At stated by @Michael Broughton you can use `RETURNING` clause to get id of YOUR last inserted row. Unfortunately this is Oracle SQL extension and is not well supported by JDBC. Generally your question does not make sense. In multi-user  environment there is nothing like "last inserted row".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:
If there is a natural key to go with your generated ID (you inserted columns that comprise a unique key), then selecting for the row with those key values will work.

You can use a RETURNING clause on an insert statement to return the ID column value, however this is not supported in all middleware connections.

If the trigger checks to see if you have already set the id field on insert and only fetches the sequence.nextvalue if you are passing in a null for that column, then do the ID sequence fetch yourself and include that value in your insert statement.

If the table was set up with audit columns (created_user / created_Date sort of things) then you can always select the last inserted row by you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [sequence pseudocolumn](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm) `CURRVAL` to get the current value of the sequence:

```
SELECT sequence_name.CURRVAL
FROM   DUAL;
```

Comment: This wont work, if another user inserts a row between that and an insert

Comment: The question is "How to get id of last row inserted in oracle" if you meant to get the last row inserted by a specific user or in a specific action then you probably need to clarify that in the question.

Comment: @Graham, that's not true. `currval` returns the most recent sequence value *for the current session*. It will never return a value retrieved in other sessions.

Comment: So if I get the currval and then do the insert - is it guaranteed that another session wont get the next value?  What if I never do the insert, will the next value remain missing from the sequence?

Comment: No, you have to do the insert first because. CURRVAL has no value until your session has performed a NEXTVAL (currently being done for you in the trigger). And yes, it will cache your last session value. You need to be very careful though as if your operations are happening through a connection pool you must ensure that your CURVAL happens on the same transactional connection as the insert - which may be awkward depending on your sql processing framework - which is the main reason that I tend not to use it.